# Creating DateSlider for display GFS data in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to adapt script from Daniel Wiell on accessing [GFS data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/359137/97103) and add the [DateSlider](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/353168/97103) on it. Unfortunately no success.

My goal is can access 24-hour forecast data from every date that I chosed from the slider. My code is below:

```
var region = ee.Geometry(Map.getBounds(true))

// Strip time off current date/time
var today = ee.Date(new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0])
var start_period = ee.Date('2015-07-01');

var collection = ee.ImageCollection('NOAA/GFS0P25')
  .select('total_precipitation_surface')
  // Might not have date for today, so include yesterday too
  .filterDate(today.advance(-1, 'day'), today.advance(1, 'day'))
  // Sort so latest can be picked by taking first
  .sort('system:time_start', false)


function forecast(hours) {
  var image = collection
    .filterMetadata('forecast_hours', 'equals', hours)
    // Since colleciton is sorted descending, if there are forecasts 
    // for both yesterday and today, first() will give today.
    .first()
  var date = image.date().advance(hours, 'hours')
  return image
    .set('date', date.format())
}

// UI widgets needs client-side data. evaluate()
// to get client-side values of start and end period
ee.Dictionary({start: start_period, end: today.advance(1, 'day')})
  .evaluate(renderSlider) 

function renderSlider(dates) {
  var slider = ui.DateSlider({
    start: dates.start.value, 
    end: dates.end.value, 
    period: 1, // Every 5 days
    onChange: renderDateRange
  })
  Map.add(slider)
}

function renderDateRange(dateRange) {
  var gfs1day = ee.ImageCollection([24].map(forecast))
      .filterDate(dateRange.start(), dateRange.end());
      
  var vis = {min: 0, max: 200, palette: [
      'cccccc','f9f3d5','dce2a8','a8c58d','77a87d','ace8f8',
      '4cafd9','1d5ede','001bc0','9131f1','e983f3','f6c7ec'
    ]}
  var layer = ui.Map.Layer(gfs1day, vis, 'GFS 1-day')
  Map.layers().reset([layer])
}
```

Link to GEE [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/d6229423bfddf6284c31c721b708c7bb)

Any idea where my error is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you try to achieve with the function `forecast`... I think that is not necessary. I would recommend to filter the complete collection first on band and metadata:

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('NOAA/GFS0P25')
  .select('total_precipitation_surface')
  .filterMetadata('forecast_hours', 'equals', 24)
```

Then you can simply filter that collection with the daterange returned from the `ui.DateSlider`. You can then add the collection to the map, eventually by forcing a type of aggregation (I chose `median()`):

```
function renderDateRange(dateRange) {
  var gfs1day = collection
      .filterDate(dateRange.start(), dateRange.end())
      .median(); // make a composite of the collection
      
  var vis = {min: 0, max: 200, palette: [
      'cccccc','f9f3d5','dce2a8','a8c58d','77a87d','ace8f8',
      '4cafd9','1d5ede','001bc0','9131f1','e983f3','f6c7ec'
    ]}
  var layer = ui.Map.Layer(gfs1day, vis, 'GFS 1-day')
  Map.layers().reset([layer])
}
```

[Link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/bf290fa03d1cd17957a01a219224cc9a)

Comment: Thank you, its worked! Btw, is it possible whenever I open the link, the forecast automatically show for current date (without move the slider to other date and back to current date)?

Comment: [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/2299df8c250a3479225d556b04f0e65f)

Comment: Thank you @Kuik you made my day.