# Preventing SLD visualisation rendered as RGB in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, sld

Following this [answered](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/372683/97103) question, I would like to visualise the rainfall forecast using specified threshold. I tried to use Styled Layer Descriptor (SLD). But unfotunately, but it doesn't work. All pixels are converted to RGB.

How to prevent that? Because standard visualisation is hard to see the rainfall category based on milimeters value. I really want to visualise it based on SLD and rendered as milimeters.
Is there any option that I can follow?

```
var region = ee.Geometry(Map.getBounds(true))

// Strip time off current date/time
var today = ee.Date(new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0])
var start_period = ee.Date('2015-07-01');

var collection = ee.ImageCollection('NOAA/GFS0P25')
  .select('total_precipitation_surface')
  .filterMetadata('forecast_hours', 'equals', 24)

// UI widgets needs client-side data. evaluate()
// to get client-side values of start and end period
ee.Dictionary({start: start_period, end: today.advance(1, 'day')})
  .evaluate(renderSlider) 

function renderSlider(dates) {
  var slider = ui.DateSlider({
    start: dates.start.value, 
    end: dates.end.value, 
    period: 1, // Every 5 days
    onChange: renderDateRange
  })
  Map.add(slider)
}

// Define an SLD style of discrete intervals to apply to the image.
var visRainForecast =
  '<RasterSymbolizer>' +
    '<ColorMap  type="interval" extended="false" >' +
      '<ColorMapEntry color="#cccccc" opacity="1.0" quantity="1" label="No Rain" />' +
      '<ColorMapEntry color="#f9f3d5" opacity="1.0" quantity="10" label="1-10" />' +
      '<ColorMapEntry color="#dce2a8" opacity="1.0" quantity="20" label="11-20" />' +
      '<ColorMapEntry color="#a8c58d" opacity="1.0" quantity="30" label="21-30" />' +
      '<ColorMapEntry color="#77a87d" opacity="1.0" quantity="40" label="31-40" />' +
      '<ColorMapEntry color="#ace8f8" opacity="1.0" quantity="60" label="41-60" />' +
      '<ColorMapEntry color="#4cafd9" opacity="1.0" quantity="80" label="61-80" />' +
      '<ColorMapEntry color="#1d5ede" opacity="1.0" quantity="100" label="81-100" />' +
      '<ColorMapEntry color="#001bc0" opacity="1.0" quantity="120" label="101-120" />' +
      '<ColorMapEntry color="#9131f1" opacity="1.0" quantity="150" label="121-150" />' +
      '<ColorMapEntry color="#e983f3" opacity="1.0" quantity="200" label="151-200" />' +
      '<ColorMapEntry color="#f6c7ec" opacity="1.0" quantity="1000" label="&gt; 200" />' +
    '</ColorMap>' +
  '</RasterSymbolizer>'; 


function renderDateRange(dateRange) {
  var gfs1day = collection
      .filterDate(dateRange.start(), dateRange.end())
      .median(); // make a composite of the collection
      
  var vis = {min: 0, max: 200, palette: [
      'cccccc','f9f3d5','dce2a8','a8c58d','77a87d','ace8f8',
      '4cafd9','1d5ede','001bc0','9131f1','e983f3','f6c7ec'
    ]}
  var layer = ui.Map.Layer(gfs1day, vis, 'GFS 1-day')
  var layer2 = ui.Map.Layer(gfs1day.sldStyle(visRainForecast), {}, 'GFS 1-day SLD')
  Map.layers().reset([layer, layer2])
}
```

GEE [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/7cf6e52c3dbae35f6b352914409c7726)

Comment: If you use `sldStyle` the output will always be RGB

Comment: @blindjesse noted. What should I use then? To display rainfall using custom class or mm threshold, and rendered as mm. Any advise? Or this is not possible in gee?

Comment: It is not clear what is not working. Your RasterSymbolizer has different colours for each interval, so the result will be color. What kind of result do you want ?

Comment: @CiprianTomoiagă when the user click the map to inspect the layer, I am expecting to get milimeters value eventhough if rendered using sldstyles. But I understand as blindjesse said above its not possible and will always be RGB